Update Dom With Result from Ajax with Action Event Not Working
I'm Developing a Comment Replay System As any Social Media website But Using YII2 Framework
I Created Wedget To Show a list of Comments On Some Items ( like products )
Each Comment is With button "Replay" to allow user to send replay for this comment
Or Add new comment to The Item (product).
Using Ajax.post i do the post and retrive the new inserted Comment.
My Poroblem is:
When i Post the request and get the result
How To Append This result ( Best Way) So THAT IF THE BUTTON OF NEWLY INSERTED COMMENT PRESSED WILL FIRE
This Will Send the post and get result..
$.ajax({
  url: '$url',
  type: 'POST',
  data: formData,
  success: function(result) {
    if (result.success === 1) {
      //alert(result.msg);
      var new_comment = result.data;
      $(new_comment).appendTo('#comment_' + id + '_container');
      //$('#comment_'+id+'_container').append(new_comment);
      $(bdySelector).val('');
      $('.hideme_' + id).toggleClass('d-none');
      return false;
    } else
      $(bdySelector).val('');

    $('#errors' + id).removeClass('d-none').innerText(result.errors);
    return true;
  }

this code shoul work for new inserted comment but its not
$(document).on('click', '.ShowDialog', function(e) {
  var id = document.getElementById(e.target.id).getAttribute('data-comment-id');
  $('.hideme_' + id).toggleClass('d-none');
});


in short : I need to append some HTML RESULT into Continer
but this inserted HTML Result is not responding to my click event on it's own buttons
i have tried this but not working
$.ajax({
  url: '$url',
  type: 'POST',
  data: formData,
  success: function(result) {
    if (result.success === 1) {
      //alert(result.msg);
      var new_comment = result.data;
      $(new_comment).appendTo('#comment_' + id + '_container');
      //$('#comment_'+id+'_container').append(new_comment);
      $(bdySelector).val('');
      $('.hideme_' + id).toggleClass('d-none');
      return false;
    } else
      $(bdySelector).val('');

    $('#errors' + id).removeClass('d-none').innerText(result.errors);
    return true;
  }


do you see how facebook allow you to comment and replay a comment .. I am Asking how to do like that in php with Yii2 ..

Both your calls to $.ajax() are missing the final })

What are id and bdySelector?

Please proofread your post. You have lots of spelling errors, more than I'm willing to correct for you.

What's the difference between the first $.ajax() call and the second one? If they're the same, why did you post it twice?

There's no need to call document.getElementById() here: document.getElementById(e.target.id). It's the same as e.target.

"this code shoul work for new inserted comment but its not" - if that code already executed before you added the new elements(?), then it should indeed work for all newly inserted elements with the class ShowDialog. But we can't tell from the mere snippets you have shown here, what is actually going wrong. What have you done so far, to try and properly debug the issue?

My Problem is Solved Using This Line
$(document).on('click','.add_comment', function(e) {}

My Old Wrong One Was : With Out $(document)
$('#add_comment_'+$comment->id).on('click', function(e) {}


My Ajax Result Is Come backe Formated As Comment Block
So I just Append It Using :
$.ajax(
            {
            url: '$url',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            success: function (result) {
                if(result.success === 1){
                        $(bdySelector).val('');
                        $('.hideme_' + id).toggleClass('d-none');
                        var new_comment =result.data;
                        var new_nxt =$('#comment_'+id+'_container');
                        **$(new_nxt).append(new_comment);**
                }
                else{
                    $(bdySelector).val('');
                    $('#errors'+id).removeClass('d-none').innerText(result.errors);
                    return true;
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                $(bdySelector).val('');
                $('#errors'+id).removeClass('d-none').innerText('$errMsg');
                return false;
            }
    });

